# Connect JIRA to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, jira

I'm trying to connect Jira to external database. The main goal is to connect to Jira's database from Visual Studio.

When I finish the whole sequence of steps in the JIRA walkthrough ( https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Connecting+JIRA+to+SQL+Server+2008 ) I get this message in my browser window:

> Oops - an error has occurred
>   System Error
>   Cause:
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException .

After that there are stack trace, build info, server info, etc.
(full report is on my goo-docs: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BwJaBRG-2a9gNGNwY2ZESlMzT0E )

I've searched in google, but didn't find anything relevant.

Also I've tried to connect Jira to MySQL 5.5, and tried to do it on another machine (with win 7), with the very same result. Here is the process i'm following:

1. create db "jiradb" in SQL Server Management Studio
2. create login "jiradbuser", disable password policy, set default db to "jiradb", set user mappings as it is in documentation: jiradbuser has roles: public, db_owner
3. Enable tcp/ip on server
4. set mixed auth on server
5. configure Jira with Jira Configuration Tool, test connection (successful).

Also I've installed new Jira copy and set SQL Server 2008 database while installing (instead of internal hsql db), no effect, as with mySQL too.

My system settings:

- Win xp sp3
- Jira 5.1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you asked **Atlassian support** ??

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this issue is solved. The reason was in wrong customizing of MS SQL database. For example I set the default database for new user - jiradb, but needed master. Besides, there should not be role db_owner in user mappings, and should be datareader and datawriter.
I’ll be glad to help anybody who needs more info about this issue